# Decompose $ n^n$ in form of prime numbers.?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I want to calculate $n^n$. But the problem is calculating it in simple way is very cumbersome work.

So I want to convert it into form $2^a \cdot 3^b \cdot 5^c \ldots$ (prime powers) so that i can calculate it faster. Is there any better way to compute these prime powers $ a,b,c ...$.

$1\le n\le 10^5$

Comment: This has nothing to do with [tag:binomial-coefficients], please read the tag description before applying a tag. Also [tag:elementary-number-theory] is better suited than [tag:number-theory].

Comment: I don't see how prime factoring $n$, raising each factor by $n$, and then multiplying those factors is any easier (probably a lot more difficult) than multiplying $n$ by itself $n$ times.

Comment: @naslundx - I agree.  But if you want the factorisation of $n^n$ then it would be easier to start with the factorisation of $n$

Comment: @Henry Absolutely, but that wasn't the question as I understood it.

Comment: Note that you can raise to the power $n$ by computing $n^2, n^4, n^8 \dots$ and multiplying together the ones you need.

Answer (score 3):

Write $n$ in terms of its prime factors and then multiply all the exponents by $n$, since $\left(x^a y^b\right)^n = x^{an} y^{bn}$.

If you cannot do the prime factorisation yourself, there are webpages which do, such as http://www.se16.info/js/factor.htm .